# PHP decoding json and display it

Tags: php, json

I need to decode a json file and display it in the page..
My code is not working, and i don't know whats wrong.
The output is just a blank page.

**Here is the json file.**.

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Jhaimee",
         "uid": 10000
      },
      {
         "name": "Ally",
         "uid": 10000133
      },
      {
         "name": "Macers",
         "uid": 1000056
      },
      {
         "name": "Diego",
         "uid": 100004
      },
      {
         "name": "Killersmile",
         "uid": 1000050
      },
      {
         "name": "Joel",
         "uid": 1000011
      }
   ]
}
```

**I want the output to be..**

```
Jhaimee
Ally
Macers
Diego
Killersmile
Joel
```

**Here is my php.**

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT name,uid FROM user WHERE uid IN  (SELECT  recipients FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0 ORDER BY message_count DESC) AND uid != me() LIMIT 10&access_token=xxxx");
$data = json_decode($data, true);
echo $data[0]["name"];
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Step one: [Enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393)

Comment: To display the names, you can just do: `foreach ($data['data'] as $sub) { echo "$sub\n"; }`.

Comment: Sure about initial var $data contains json string?

Answer (score 3):

The outermost array key should be data
`echo $data['data'][0]['name']`
`foreach($data['data'] as $person){ echo $person['name'] . "<br />\n"; }`

Comment: Is theres a way to display the names without using foreach? Just using echo?

Comment: You could use `echo print_r($data['data'], true);` just to dump the array out. To format it, though, you have to iterate through the array